# rails wicked Missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, rubygems

I have BIG problem!
Please help!

Ruby 2.0, Rails 4, gem 'wicked'
I want make wizard!

I must do 3 steps:
1st - build Client (Client.new)
2nd - build Order (Order.new)
3rd - Check data and confirm!

So, I created controller:

```
class TransactionOrdersController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :client, :order, :confirm

  def show
    case step
    when :client
      @client = Client.new
      render 'client' and return
    when :order
      @order = Order.new
      render 'order' and return
    when :confirm
    end
  end

  def update
    case step
    when :client
      @client = Client.new(params[:client].permit(:name, :inn, :code))
      next_step
    when :order
      @order = Order.new(params[:order].permit(:city_id, :employee_id, :client_id, :ordersum, :startdate,
 :finishdate, :orderdate, :ordernum, :order_id, :continue, :status))
      next_step
    when :confirm
    end
  end

end
```

1st step present, but if I click submit, I have err

```
Missing template transaction_orders/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:ru], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder, :haml]}
```

So, what I need to do for fix this problem!
Say me, what I doing wrong?

```
rake routes

transaction_order GET    /transaction_orders/:id(.:format)                         transaction_orders#show
                            PATCH  /transaction_orders/:id(.:format)                         transaction_orders#update
                            PUT    /transaction_orders/:id(.:format)                         transaction_orders#update
```

Comment: you have to do either render or redirect in your update method. by default rails is trying to render update view file which you clearly dont have

Comment: can you post your routes file and or `rake routes`